# redundancy in design of classes ( CartItem and OrderItem) in shoppingcart application

Tags: java, jpa, shopping-cart

I am trying to design and code a basic store web application in java using jpa.
When a user selects products in a `ShoppingCart` ,I create a list of `Cartitem`s.
The Cartitem's lifespan is tied to the cart.When a cart is deleted all its cartitems must go.
(The cart is deleted after a user finishes purchasing)
Afterwards these selections need to be converted into an order.I created a list of `OrderItem`s in each `Order`.Then I found that each Cartitem has a corresponding OrderItem.
The lifespan of a Orderitem is tied to the Order.

I am a beginner at java/javaee..I would like to know if I am on the right track as far as the design is concerned..
Is this the correct way to design such an application.The `CartItem` and `OrderItem` classes look too much alike ,that I am wondering if there is any redundancy.

My entity classes now look like this.

```
class ShoppinCart{

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="order")
    private List<CartItem> citems;
    ...
}

class CartItem{
    Product product;
    int quantity;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    ShoppingCart cart;
}

class Order{
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="order")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItem;
    private Date orderDate;
    private Customer customer;
}

class OrderItem{
    Product product;
    int quantity;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    Order order;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes CartItem and OrderItem are redundant. You don't need to store a cart reference inside the CartItem.
In my opinion a ShoppingCart is just an order which hasn't been finalized. You'll probably need to add a status to your order, pending, dispatched, cancelled etc, so the shopping card could be just an order with a pending status. If you need a separate class then just wrap it so a ShoppingCart has one Order (and no CartItem list).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create **common superclas** SomeItem and if you need some additional info (like itemDeliveryDate) add it to the child class. Having **CartItem as parameter to OrderItem constructor** would be helpfull.

Also there is no need for navigability from items to the holdin object (Cart or Order), **remove the @ManyToOne marked** properties.